# Use GraphQL Query to get results form MongoDB after aggregation with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo

so i have following problem.
I have a mongoDB collection and a corresponding mongoose model which looks like this.

```
export const ListItemSchema = new Schema<ListItemSchema>({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  parentId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false },
});

export const TestSchema = new Schema<Test>(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    list: { type: [ListItemSchema], required: false },
  }
);
```

As you can see, my TestSchema holds an Array of ListItems inside -> TestSchema is also my Collection in MongoDB.

Now i want to query only my ListItems from a Test with a specific ID.
Well that was not that big of a problem at least from the MongoDB side.
I use MongoDB Aggregation Framework for this and call my aggregation inside a custom Resolver.

Here is the code to get an array of only my listItems from a specific TestModel

```
const test = TestModel.aggregate([
      {$match: {_id: id}},
      {$unwind: "$list"},
      {
        $match: {
          "list.parentId": {$eq: null},
        },
      },
      {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$list"}},
    ]);
```

This is the result

```
[ { _id: randomId,
    title: 't',
    parentId: null },
  { _id: randomId,
    title: 'x'
    parentId: null 
} ]
```

The Query to trigger the resolver looks like this and is placed inside my Test Type Composer.

```
query getList {
    test(testId:"2f334575196fe042ea83afbf", parentId: null) {
    title
  }
}
```

So far so good... BUT! Ofc my query will fail or will result in a not so good result^^ because GraphQL expects data based on the Test-Model but receives a completely random array.

So after a lot of typing here is the question:

How do i have to change my query to receive the list array?
Do i have to adjust the query or is it something with mongoose?

i really stuck at this point so any help would be awesome!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your issue correctly.
In your graphql, try to leave out exclamation mark(!) from the Query type.

something like :

```
type Query {
   test: TestModel
}
```

instead of

```
type Query {
   test: TestModel!
}
```

then you'll get the error message in console but still be able to receive any form of data.